# Unhandled Exception using DotNetZip

Tags: vb.net, dotnetzip

I've been using DotNetZip for a month or so now and i like how it has worked but today my program started having a new issue that I'm clueless on.

During the zipping process it throws this error up and windows displays their "*program name* has stopped working" box.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: s:\(file path)\filename.pdf
at Ionic.Zip.SharedUtilities.GetFileLength(string fileName)
at ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.MaybeUnsetCompressionMethodForWriting(int32 cycle)
at Ionic.zip.Zipentry.WriteHeader(Stream s, Int32 cycle)
at Ionic.zip.ZipEntry.Write(Stream s)
at Ionic.zip.zipfile.save()
at ZipAJob_Instant.ConsoleMain.Main() in C:\users\(my name)\Documents\visual studio 2012\projects\zipAjob_Instant\zipAJob_Win32.vb:line 71
```

Line 71 refers to where i call zip.save()

Comment: Have you confirmed that `s:\(file path)\filename.pdf` exists and the identity the program runs under has access to the file?

Comment: It existed when i started running the program but was NOT in the folder after the error showed up. I'm thinking that the file was moved (by an employee working in that folder) during the zip process and that was what caused the error.

Comment: Well, it looks like you have found the problem. Perhaps you could check File.Exists for each file immediately before you add it to the zip file. Or, if it essential that all the files are added to the archive, take an exclusive lock on each of the files before starting the zipping and release them one-by-one as you add them. If zipping takes a long time, maybe copy them to a temporary location and zip the copies.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, I take that what happened is exactly what happened to me a while ago.

I was getting a list of files to zip and stored into memory. The I would go zipping them one by one until this exception was thrown. The cause was someone removed the file **after** I got the list, but **before** I got the opportunity to zip it. This occured on a shared folder, btw.